# KeyError: 'label'

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть код для загрузки данных. Все нормально работает с первыми двумя сетами, но какая-то фигня случается с тестовыми сетами. Выдает ошибку. Версия Python 3.6.8

```
def unpickle(file):
 with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
     dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='latin1', errors = "label")
 data = dict['data']
 labels = dict['label']
 return data, labels

x,y = unpickle("datasets/trainset.pickle")
x_valid, y_valid = unpickle("datasets/validset.pickle")
```

Код который выдает ошибку:

```
x_test, y_test = unpickle("datasets/testset.pickle")
```

Ошибка:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-b83ffbb235e8> in <module>
----> 1 x_test, y_test = unpickle("datasets/testset.pickle")

<ipython-input-32-ad4fd8e1938a> in unpickle(file)
      3      dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='latin1', errors = "label")
      4  data = dict['data']
----> 5  labels = dict['label']
      6  return data, labels

KeyError: 'label'
```

Прошу помочь подсказать. Загружала только для x_label данные, и вычеркивала label. Но в сете test label выдает уже другую ошибку:

```
x_label, y_label = unpickle("datasets/testlabel.pickle")
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-3cb98d0c3c8b> in <module>
----> 1 x_label, y_label = unpickle("datasets/testlabel.pickle")

<ipython-input-32-ad4fd8e1938a> in unpickle(file)
      2  with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
      3      dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='latin1', errors = "label")
----> 4  data = dict['data']
      5  labels = dict['label']
      6  return data, labels

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Проблема в Сете или коде? Может можно что-то исправить?

Comment: Проблема решена. Проверила Сет, там просто нет атрибута лейбл. И второй сет просто пустой.

Comment: Только не сет (`set`), а дикт (`dict` - словарь). И не используйте переменные с именами, совпадающие с именами стандартных типов (тот же `dict`) или функций.

Comment: Функция unpickel была дана по заданию профессором университета, ничего не могу с ней сделать, а сет, потому что это dataset’ы для меня.